# ReactJS - Construct html from mapping

Tags: reactjs

> **I found the solution I wanted and it works, see below.....**

I know I am doing something stupid but I am having a mental block this morning and would appreciate some help. I am trying to construct html from a mapping:

**In my render:**

```
< ul>
  { arryItems.map(this.foo.bind(this)) }
< /ul>
```

**Calling function:**

```
foo(arry, i) {
 let result = '';

 if (arry.children != undefined && arry.children.length > 0) { 
    result= ( 
             <div key= {i}>{arry.name}
               {arry.children.map(function(child, ix){
                 <p key= {ix}>{child.name}</p>
               })}
             </div>
            )
  } else {
         result = (<div>{arry.name}</div>)
  }

   return result;
};
```

I am trying to return back html.

> **While I am receiving no error, the < p>{child.name}< /p> is not in the return html result.**

Can anyone point out what is so blatantly obvious with my thinking that I cannot figure this out?

Comment: Just to note, you have `i` declared twice - one for you `foo` function, and another for your children map function.

Comment: Also, do you need the bind on the foo function?

Comment: Yea, I know, I'll change one so as not to confuse anyone, but still does not solve my issue.

Comment: Tom, it would be nice if you could provide the code. ;)

Comment: it could be worth you creating a jsFiddle with your code so we can see exactly what you've got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **I appreciate Dominic's help but I like my solution better, as it is compact and it checks if there are no children:**

```
 foo(arry, index) {
    let children = this.getChildren(arry)
    return (
        <div key={index}>{arry.name}
            { children }
        </div>
    )
}

getChildren(arry){
    let result = [];
    if(arry.children != undefined && arry.children.length > 0){
         arry.children.map(function(child, ix){
             result.push(<p key={ix}>{child.name}</p>)
         })
    }
    return result;
}

render() {
   return (
       <section>
         { arryItems.map(this.foo.bind(this)) }
       </section>
   );
}
```

Comment: Compactness != better.  I prefer Dominic's solution as it's far more readable.  His solution could be tweaked slightly if there are no children.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to render a component to an html string? React does this with [renderToString](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdomserver.rendertostring). e.g:

```
var Task = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <li>{this.props.task.text}</li>
    );
  }
});

var Tasks = React.createClass({
  getTasks() {
    return [
      { _id: 1, text: 'This is task 1' },
      { _id: 2, text: 'This is task 2' },
      { _id: 3, text: 'This is task 3' }
    ];
  },

  renderTasks() {
    return this.getTasks().map(task => {
      return <Task key={task._id} task={task} />;
    });
  },

  render() {
    return (
        <ul>
          {this.renderTasks()}
        </ul>
    );
  }
});

var html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(Tasks);
```

Note that since 0.14 this method has been split out to `react-dom/server` package, earlier versions it's just in the `react` package.

Comment: What is wrong with my 'compact' way? I am getting no error, however, the element with the {child.name} is not in the return result. And what happens with your mapping of the children if their are no children?

Comment: @SarasotaSun can you give an example of how you are calling foo?

Comment: Updated my question above to reflect the calling of foo